# How to layout figures/tables close to each other from the top

Tags: floats

How to layout figures/tables close to each other from the top.

Here is the test code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Now I get:

[image]

I want:

[image]

Comment: Do not let your figures/tables float, i.e. don't use the figure/table environments. You still can have captions with the `\captionof{figure/table}{caption text}` and the corresponding fiures/tables can be referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution. Defne a newenvironment for figure and table that have caption ability.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figurehere}  % other name for table, say tablehere
{\def\@captype{figure}}      % for table, replace figure for table
{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figurehere}
{\def\@captype{figure}}
{}

\newenvironment{tablehere}
{\def\@captype{table}}
{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figurehere}
\caption{A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!}
\end{figurehere}

\begin{tablehere}
\caption{A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!}
\end{tablehere}

\begin{figurehere}
\caption{A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!}
\end{figurehere}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your setup correctly, the three floats are placed on a floats-only page. If this is the case, you can proceed by (i) redefining the length parameter `\@fptop` and (ii) using `[t]` and `[h]` location specifiers for the floats.

In the example below, the thin lines are drawn by the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\makeatletter % use this instruction b/c "\@fptop"  contains a "special" character
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt} % in floats-only pages, don't insert `vfill` at the top
\makeatother
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!A very long caption!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```